# function which returns multiple arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I would like to write a C++ function which reads a file (e.g. a table with 2 columns or more) and returns each column as an array. How can I do that? And how can I read the arrays from this function in the main program?

I can do that for a file with 1 column (1 array), so that the function returns a pointer. But how can I return many arrays (or pointers to these arrays) and read them later in the main program?

example "table.txt":

```
1 10
2 20
3 30
4 40
5 50
```

Comment: read on 2-dimensions arrays, or matrices.

Comment: Why array? Why pointer? C++ has better* stuff (`std::vector` for example). (*: better in most cases; pointers and arrays also have their right to exist)

Comment: Just a thought: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9753b30e62ee6bd1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you have are key value pairs. The best thing to do is to return an std::map from your function. Here is what it can look like:

```
std::map<int, int> parseFile()
{
}
```

As you will be parsing the file, add the key value pairs as an std::pair to your std::map.

Comment: @armanali the question specifies that the data is a table which may be 2 columns or more.

Comment: @Veritas then you can do vector of vectors, which will look like this: std::vector<std::vector<int>>.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a vector containing vectors. Basically you would break each line into the appropriate words and push them on the right vector for the corresponding column in the vector container.

Answer (score 0):

Declare the arrays in the caller and pass them in through arguments.

```
void fill(int *a, int *b, int *c) {
  a[0] = b[0] = c[0] = 1;
  //...
}

void func() {
  int a[10], b[10], c[10];
  fill(a, b, c);
  //...
}
```

Alternatively, you could define a struct with all the element types and return a single array of those structs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking of pointers (more C than C++... in my point of view), you can return that same single pointer, but that pointer must be pointing to a struct that holds your two arrays pointers.

Something like:

```
typedef struct _two_arrays{
 /*Assuming it is an array of ints*/
 int *arr_1; 
 int *arr_2;
}TwoArr;

TwoArr *yourFunction(/*Argss*/){
  TwoArr *arrs = (TwoArr*)malloc(sizeOf(TwoArr));
  /*Columns to your arrays ...*/
  arrs->arr_1 = yourArr1;
  arrs->arr_2 = yourArr2;
  return arrs; 
}
```

Or, in a c++ way, you could use `std::vector<std::vector<YOUR_TYPE>>`

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are new to C++. 
Vector is data structure that you can use instead of arrays.
You can find more information here []http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/.
Without complicating it much you could declare two vectors cloumn1 and column2 (you can think of them as infinite sized arrays) in your main function and call loadMatrixFromFile as below:

```
    vector<int>  column1,vector<int>  column2;

    if(!loadMatrixFromFile(inputFile,column1,column2))
    {
            cerr << "Uh oh, failed in loading matrix form file" << endl;
            exit(1);
    }
```

And create the function as below:

```
    bool loadMatrixFromFile(ifstream & inputFile,vector<int> & col1,vector<int> & col2)
    {
      while (inputFile)
       {
            string line;
            getline(inputFile,line);

                    int n;
                    stringstream tempLine(line);
                    for (int i=0;i<2;i++)
                    {
                            tempLine>>n;
                            if (i==0)
                                col1.push_back(n);
            else
                col2.push_back(n);
                    }
       }
    return true;
    }
```

After executing the function, the vectors column1, column2 would contain the column values from the file.

If you are comfortable using vectors,then instead of declaring one vector for each column you can use vector of vectors ( as in array of array )  to create vector that could hold the vector of each column .